# Copying outlets, actions to new storyboard along with UI elements?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I am having a great deal of difficulty getting autolayout constraints to do what I would like when I go to a 3.5" iPhone screen, and have decided that I would like to setup a separate storyboard that will launch when someone runs my app on an iPhone 4. I have seen some answers on this forum that explain how to accomplish this.

I have a created a second storyboard, and was able to copy all of my UI content from my main storyboard. Unfortunately, it does not appear that the outlets and actions have been copied over along with the physical buttons, labels, etc.

So my question is how should I set up this new storyboard? I tried the "duplicate" command for the storyboard, but that creates a code version of the storyboard and not the UI design storyboard that I need in order to shrink my content down to the smaller screen size. I am assuming that I can use the same custom view controller header and implementation files that have all of my code from the original design made for a 4" iPhone.

Of course, if there is some easier / better way of accomplishing this, any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If at all possible, I'd recommend you try not to do separate storyboards just to cater for the different screen sizes. A 3.5" iPhone screen and an 4" aren't that different in size, and depending on the complexity of your app it's a whole extra storyboard to maintain, and a whole lot of duplication whenever you need to make a change.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, and I tend to agree. Less code, fewer storyboards = an app that is going to be cleaner, run faster, etc. I just changed the main storyboard to the 3.5" format and redesigned it with the hope that autolayout would work better going to a larger screen, but for some reason I am still getting a text field and a button image that are stretching way out to fill up the space. It's so bizarre. Everything else just spreads out across the screen, but this one text field and button image are around double the height they are supposed to be. It's maddening.

Comment: Hmm... Do you have height constraints on them? Or are they pinned to views above / below them?

Comment: I just put hard constraints on height and width and that solved the problem of the stretching elements. It looks pretty good, but I think having a separate layout for the 3.5" would still be more ideal. I am going to tweak these constraints to get something that I like better, but if someone can chime in on my OP that would be awesome. Having the flexibility of a second storyboard would give me more control.

Comment: As you mentioned in your question, the only way is to use the same .h and .m files for all of your ViewControllers in your 4" stroyboard, and you have to do all the connections again. I have done this before, it is tedious but sometimes there is no other option to get what you want.

Comment: Seconding @JamesFrost 's comment. Auto Layout was specifically introduced to address your situation (different screen sizes). Figure out why your constraints are not working correctly before introducing a separate storyboard.